# Javascript outside the browser

Tags: javascript, windows, command-line

I'm looking at writing some code in Javascript to run as a command line program, unrelated to browsers or the Web; it would need access to files and directories as normal for a command line utility. What's the best Windows implementation of Javascript for this scenario, with regard to stability and performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take a look at [Nodejs](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: Node.js may be too much for rwallace's needs, but [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), which Node.js runs on, might be a simpler alternative. Node.js is for writing servers, and I think V8 may be more appropriate for this use.

Comment: Right, I don't need the server framework, but V8 definitely looks like a strong contender. I'd be interested if anyone knows how it stacks up against the alternatives.

Comment: @Wylie true, but V8 isn't a commandline app in itself. You'd have to compile a wrapper to V8 to process a script and run it. Node does have an API for server stuff, but it's equally well equipped to do local file I/O; the same is true of many scripting languages like Ruby and Python so I wouldn't let that put you off.

Comment: V8 is an engine more than an api. I'm not aware of there being native support for the types of operations you mentioned - e.g. file I/O. Yes, Node is primarily looked at for it's server capabilities, but it is more of a developed api than going straight to V8. Maybe there are some other apis written to run on v8 I don't know about yet, but I'm not sure working with v8 directly is the way you want to go.

Comment: Correction to my own comment - V8 does come with a shell. I'm not sure how much of a file IO API you get with plain V8, so Node may still be worth looking at.

Comment: Here's a link to the file I/O you get with Node: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.4/api/fs.html#file_System

Comment: Chrome is not Open Source, so I rather try jsdb or the Aptana-solution.

Answer (score 3):

I use [jsdb](http://www.jsdb.org/) or in windows [cscript](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490887.aspx). In some editors (Editplus in my case, i've also use Aptana) you can configure running js-files directly from within the editor.

Ofcourse in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) you could create javascript unrelated to the browser (apart from the output, which can be [console.]logged or written to some div. In some cases it can be a problem that the code is `eval`led though.

Further, this [blog entry](http://www.phpied.com/javascript-shell-scripting/) may give you extra information

Comment: Any link to Stoyan's site is a +1 from me :)